# Automatically remove filters in Excel file on Azure

Tags: excel, azure

I have Excel files in Azure Blob Storage, which I use to load data to Azure SQL database using Azure Data Factory.
Problem is that, those Excel files have filters applied on one row and then ADF can't read that file, so I had to manually remove those filters.
I would like to automate that process and remove filters before loading them to SQL database. How could I do it? Could I run PowerShell script calling some VBA macro in this Blob Storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a blob trigger function to run when a file is uploaded on the blob. and use these codes to remove all filters from the excel sheet.

```
if (xlSheet.AutoFilter != null)
{
    xlSheet.AutoFilterMode = false;
}
```

if you have files in azure blob storage then, you can create an azure function those run on all excel file and remove all filter from excel sheets. using same above code.